# Login page in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to convert my site into PDO and I have some problems with my login page. 
This is my code but no matter what username or password I entered, I got the same thing: "Name or password is incorrect!". I checked the username and the password, everything it's correct. 
What's wrong?

```
<?php
    if($_POST['name']=="" || $_POST['password']=="")`enter code here`
    {
        print 'Fields cannot be empty !<br>
                <a href="index.php">Inapoi</a>';
        exit;
    }

    include("connnect.php");
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_name = ? AND admin_password = ?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, md5($_POST['password']));
    $stmt->execute();

    if(($stmt->fetchColumn())!=1)
    {
        print 'Name or password is incorrect!<br>
                <a href="index.php">Back</a>';
        exit;
    }

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name_admin']=$_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['password']=md5($_POST['name']);
    $_SESSION['key_admin']=session_id();
    header("location: admin.php");
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump(($stmt->fetchColumn());`

Comment: fetchColumn will never be 1,it returns either the column value or FALSE.Just remove `!=1`

Comment: @Mihai  And if column value is 1 - what's then?

Comment: If the password is 1 you have bigger fish to fry

Comment: `select *` not means that first fetched field is `password`, isn't it?

Comment: @RyanVincent I've done that ! Still doesn't work ..

Comment: Ok, here is an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55b25/1) witth some test data.

Comment: Working and tested database code: [pastebin - questions/34104734/login-page-in-pdo](http://pastebin.com/DbPVxb6D).

Comment: Quite interesting - PDO doesn't report an error for `bindParam` with a calculation. `mysqli` actually does complain. It is reported by `PHP` as a 'strict standard ' notice.

Comment: @RyanVincent no, still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

[fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

> PDOStatement::fetchColumn — Returns a single column from the next row
>   of a result set

Instead of `$stmt->fetchColumn()` you have to use  `$stmt->rowCount()`

> PDOStatement::rowCount — Returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last SQL statement

```
if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
    {
        print 'Name or password is incorrect!<br>
                <a href="index.php">Back</a>';
        exit;
    }
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

**Updated**

> PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected
>   by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT
>   COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT
>   statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number
>   of rows that will be returned

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_name = ? AND admin_password = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, md5($_POST['password']));
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->fetch();
        $row=count($result);
            /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
            if ($row== 0) {
                 print 'Name or password is incorrect!<br>
                    <a href="index.php">Back</a>';
            exit;
            }
```

Comment: For a SELECT this wont work,you need either a SELECT COUNT or store all values with fetchAll before

Comment: @Mihai you are correct i will update my answer accordingly. and thanks for updating my knowledge

Comment: Now I get this Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::query()..

Comment: @Saty Now I don't get 'Name or password is incorrect!' for anything..

Comment: you guys solve this thing yet ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Before `include("connnect.php");` add `var_dump($_POST['name']); var_dump($_POST['password']); exit;`

2) Then if you get name and password add after `$stmt->execute();` add `var_dump($stmt); exit;`

3) If have nothing in output, so the problem is in your PDO configuration

Comment: I've got my password and username..

Comment: ok, now you can delete `var_dump($_POST['name']); var_dump($_POST['password']); exit;` and do second (2 point)

Comment: Now I got this: object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(61) "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_name = ? AND admin_password = ?" }

Comment: Ok, guess you have the error here: `if(($stmt->fetchColumn())!=1)` . You need to remove **!=1** and it should look like: `if(!$stmt->fetchColumn())`

Comment: Now I don't get 'Name or password is incorrect!' for anything..

Comment: try this: `if( $stmt->fetchColumn() == FALSE)`, that should help you to resolve your issue